# How do I make variable in for loop bigger that in was

Tags: c++

I have 2 loop:

```
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  for(int j=1;j<10;j++)...}
```

The thing is to make "j" bigger by one after the loop for i finished. Something like that:

```
   int j=0;
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  j++;
  for(j;j<10;j++)...}
```

But I dont know how to do that;So if it is i=3, then j=4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset `j` to `i + 1`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  for(int j = i + 1; j < 10; ++j)
  {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{ for(j=i+1;j<10;j++) { }}
```